# Compiling PJSUA lib for python with Opus Codec Support

Tags: python-2.7

I am compiling PJSUA 2.8 with Opus Codec support, but it is not showing as available when I list the supported codecs in python, it only shows these:

> speex/16000/1 130 
>   speex/8000/1 129 
>   speex/32000/1 128 
>   iLBC/8000/1 128
>   GSM/8000/1 128 
>   PCMU/8000/1 128 
>   PCMA/8000/1 128 
>   G722/16000/1 128
>   L16/44100/1 0 
>   L16/44100/2 0

I tried configuring with "--with-opus" parameter but still not showing the codec. Any tip?

Best Regards

Cristian.